# Self Processing Page using PHP, HTML and MySQL

Tags: html, forms

Hi so I am trying to make a search bar that queries a database in MySQL using a product number and when the item is found, its relevant numerical values underneath the headings ("Item Cost", "Taxes", etc) are put into the form boxes to be used as input for my *HighCharts* graph. That was a long sentence, sorry, hopefully my JSFiddle will explain what I mean!

I have a bit of experience with Python and in my college course was taught how to make a self-processing page using it but I couldn't get it to work and since the only results online for this sort of thing were for PHP I said I'd give that a go instead!

I used PHP to conduct a search on the database originally but when hitting search it went to a 2nd page so I'd prefer it be done on the same page

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tg4wdLz6/8/)

Side question: How would I set the reset button to reset the values to 0 in the boxes? (It's okay if this is too much, I can figure it out myself I'd say)

Thanks in advance!

It asks me to include indented code as I have a JSFiddle link so here:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Pricer.ie</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="homepage.css"/>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=B612&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
        <script src="/js/themes/gray.js"></script>
        <script src="highcharts.js"></script>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav class="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li class="logo">
                    <a href=""><img src="logopricerv2.png" alt="logo" id="logo" ></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="login.py" class="logintopright" >Login</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="logout.py" class="logouttopright" >Logout</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <button class="darkmodebutton" onclick="darkFunction()">Toggle dark mode</button>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <main>
            <figure class="highcharts-figure">
                <div id="container" style="width:100%; height:400px;"></div>
                <script>
                    
                </script>
            </figure>
            <section>
                <form action="search.php" method="POST" id="search_form" autocomplete="off">
                    <label for="query">SKU :  </label>
                    <input type="text" id="query" name="query"><br><br>
                    <input type="submit" id="search_box" value="Search">
                </form>
            </section>
            <section>
                <form id="mainForm" autocomplete="off">
                    <label>Item Cost:</label>
                    <input type="number" id="icost" name="icost" step="0.01"/><br><br>
                    <label>Shipping Cost:</label>
                    <input type="number" id="scost" name="scost" step="0.01"/><br><br>     <!-- names and ids are incorrect just like this for now -->
                    <label>Taxes:</label>
                    <input type="number" id="taxes" name="taxes" step="0.01"/><br><br>     <!-- shouldnt exist as taxes is from database but sure look-->
                    <label>Listing Fee:</label>
                    <input type="number" id="listfee" name="listfee" step="0.01"/><br><br>
                    <label>Profit Margin:</label>
                    <input type="number" id="pmargin" name="pmargin" step="0.01"/><br><br>
                    <input type="submit" value="Reset">
                    <input type="submit" value="Save Changes">
                </form>
            </section>
        </main>
        <footer>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Easier to understand in the JSFiddle**

Comment: *"when hitting search it went to a 2nd page so I'd prefer it be done on the same page"* - That's exactly what the `action` attribute on the `<form>` element is doing.  You already have a `<form>` with no `action` specified, so it posts to the current page.  What's stopping you from doing the same thing in your search form?

Comment: @David sorry I'm not quite sure what you mean

Comment: Where is the php and mysql? You tagged as such.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I tagged them as they are what I am using. I can edit my question to include my original PHP code that queried my database if needed but I didn't see it relevant as it didn't work the way I wanted it to

Comment: People such as I follow those tags for a reason. We (usually) expect related code for those. By not including code or showing relevance, is misleading and makes the question unclear. If there is no relevance, then you need to remove the tags for the question.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner okay I understand, sorry about that but what should I put the tags at then? As without PHP and MySQL I have nothing else to tag with.

Comment: @DanGriffin: Basically, if you don't want the search `<form>` to post to `search.php` then remove `action="search.php"` (or change it to the page you do want to post to).

Comment: You could remove php and mysql and replace them with "html", seeing that's all there is here and possibly "javascript". However, if answers given do not solve the question, then it could eventually be a serverside issue, should there be errors on either area. Hard to say Dan but I am not the guy for "JS" stuff.

Comment: @David ohh, I know what you mean sorry, I've tried that but I'm not quite sure how to implement the PHP within the page I already have as the results from the query need to go into my input boxes

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner thanks for the advice anyway! I'm pretty new here and still trying to make sure I add the right amount of info and tags, I'll edit my question now

Comment: @DanGriffin: "I'm not quite sure" isn't really an answerable question, I'm afraid.  The code shown has no attempt to write any PHP whatsoever.  It sounds like what you're looking for are introductory tutorials on PHP, which this community doesn't provide.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, you are encouraged to start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.  As you begin to learn PHP and attempt to build your application, we can help with specific problems you encounter in the code you write.

Comment: @David okay thanks for your advice anyway, I'll give this more of a go!!